# Attribute the product of variable B and C to variable A

Tags: c++, variables, int

I have a stupid problem. I'm new in the fantastic world of programming and I'm starting now to learn. I don't know how to resolve this problem. Can someone help me?

Attribute the product of variable B and C to variable A:

I tried to write this solution but I don't know if it is correct:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()


{

    int b;
    int c;
    int a;

    cin >> b; 
    cin >> c;

    a = b * c;
    cout << a; 

    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: And what makes you think it isn't correct? What happens when you compile and run the code?

Comment: Nothing! The program has no problem. I just want it now, if this program is written correctly.

That is if what I wrote really attributes the product to the variable a or if there is another way to do it.  I know is a stupid question. But i am new in this world and I have one thousand question for learn this language.

Comment: If you run it you will see that it's correct. If you don't have any specific problems with the code and just want someone to review it https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct as to what was asked.
But follow community guide lines to ask question next time.
Just to improve upon that you can  declare the variable in a single line and do this to take input

```
int a, b, c;
cin >> b >> c;
```

It is also a good practice to assign default values when declaring variables. Like,

```
int a = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. Thanks for the advice! So to get the product of the variable a just write:

```
 int a, b, c;
 cin >> b >> c;
```

But how do I then attribute to A the value of (b + c)?